# Error: Error getting broadcast client: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport: write tcp

Tags: cryptography, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to create a channel with custom cryptomaterial (not working in fabricSample) using the command

```
 peer channel create -c myc -o orderer2.IdentityPreservationSystem.com:7050
```

and getting this error

```
Error: Error getting broadcast client: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport: write tcp 172.20.0.7:42446->172.20.0.3:7050: write: connection reset by peercontainers are running with the services of peers CA and orderers.
```

complete Output

```
 2020-01-26 19:10:00.072 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-01-26 19:10:00.232 UTC [common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig] Load -> INFO 002 Loaded configuration: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/configtx.yaml
Error: Error getting broadcast client: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport: write tcp 172.20.0.7:42446->172.20.0.3:7050: write: connection reset by peer
Usage:
  peer channel create [flags]

Flags:
  -c, --channelID string   In case of a newChain command, the channel ID to create.
  -f, --file string        Configuration transaction file generated by a tool such as configtxgen for submitting to orderer
  -t, --timeout int        Channel creation timeout (default 5)

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
  -v, --version                             Display current version of fabric peer server
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your create command. you need to specify channel transaction file(.tx) for the channel which is generated using configtxgen command.

peer channel create -c myc -f specify_the_channel_transaction_file -o orderer2.IdentityPreservationSystem.com:7050

Comment: now i am getting this error error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: existing config does not contain element for [Group]  /Channel/Application/OrgMSP but was in the read set

Comment: May i know how you have generated Crypto-Material?

Comment: Using cryptogen

Comment: Ok then please follow the below mentioned link for adding an organisation in to existing channel. And also make sure you are using correct OrganisationMSP and channel name.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html#fetch-the-configuration

Follow the above link and let me know

Comment: WHy i should add another organisation .My business logic need one organization